# Re-order mysql rows using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
| id  | url    | title  | menu_id |
------+--------+--------+----------
| 1   | http://| link 1 | 1       |
| 2   | http://| link 2 | 2       |
| 3   | http://| link 3 | 3       |
| 4   | http://| link 4 | 4       |
```

Hi, I was wondering if its possible using PHP to reorder the above to something like below. I am trying to generate a menu which can easily be reordered by clicking an up or down arrow. I have no idea where to start. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
| id  | url    | title  | menu_id |
------+--------+--------+----------
| 1   | http://| link 1 | 2       |
| 2   | http://| link 2 | 4       |
| 3   | http://| link 3 | 3       |
| 4   | http://| link 4 | 1       |
```

Comment: PHP?  Might as well use Javascript, rather than deal with a page refresh for every time you want to sort things...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went with using the following code

```
$menu_id = $_GET['page_id'];
$page_order = $_GET['page_order'];
if ($_GET['do'] == 'up') {


mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET menu_order = '$page_order' +1 WHERE id != '$menu_id' AND menu_order < '$page_order'");
mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET menu_order = menu_order -1 WHERE id = '$menu_id'");    


} else if ($_GET['do'] == 'down') {

mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET menu_order = '$page_order' -1 WHERE id != '$menu_id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET menu_order = menu_order +1 WHERE id = '$menu_id'");    


}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible, but you have to do a little bit of extra logic, it's not something that can be done in one query.

Think about the steps when you click an up/down arrow. For example, let's say that you start with the items in the order 1, 2, 3, 4 and then you click the up arrow on #3. Two things have to happen to change the order to 1, 3, 2, 4:

- ## 3's position changes to 2 (it gets decreased by 1)
- ## 2's position changes to 3 (it gets increased by 1)

So you have to change the position for the item that they clicked up on, *as well as* the one that was previously in its new position. Clicking a down arrow is almost the same, but with the increase/decrease reversed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solved it with an if statement query. Here is step by step instructions:
1. 
get the position of the item before updating mysql.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$item = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$old_position = $item["position"];
```

we had a form in the page so we get the new position from $_POST data.

```
$new_position = $_POST["position"];


we determine if we moved the item up or down

if ($new_position > $old_position) { //moved it down
$query = "UPDATE table SET position = position-1 WHERE position >= {$old_pozisyon} AND position <= {$new_pozisyon} and id <> {$id}";

}
```

and we do the same for the other condition but we make position+1 this time. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

@DaveE has the right idea but results in all sorting data being either one higher or lower (depending on direction) for the other rows. Here's my PHP/MySQL:

```
if ($direction == 'up') {
    $q1 = "UPDATE table SET sort = ($sort +1) WHERE id != $pgid AND sort = ($sort -1);";
    if($r = mysqli_query($q1, $dbsvr)) {
        $q2 = "UPDATE table SET sort = (sort -1) WHERE id = $pgid;";
        $r = mysqli_query($q2, $dbsvr);
    }
} else if ($direction == 'down') {
    $q3 = "UPDATE table SET sort = ($sort -1) WHERE id != $pgid AND sort = ($sort +1);";
    if($r = mysqli_query($q3, $dbsvr)) {
        $q4 = "UPDATE table SET sort = (sort +1) WHERE id = $pgid;";
        $r = mysqli_query($q4, $dbsvr);
    }
} else {
    echo 'no direction';
}
```

Comment: This seems to potentially lead to duplicate `sort` numbers.